# C Programming with loops for exam

Tags: c

Hi all I have an exam for one of my uni classes tomorrow and am struggling with the last practice question they gave us. It is as follows. If someone could assist me (with code, rather than verbally) with this question I would be greatly appreciative.

> Write a C program which reads integers from the keyboard, stopping when an odd number greater than 20 is entered. The total number of even and odd numbers entered should then be displayed to the screen.

---

[Edit]

So far what I have done is as follows since I am unsure on how to make it stop when a number greater than 20 is inputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
  int number; 
  int i;
  int n; 
  int val; 
  printf("Please enter numbers:"); 
  scanf("%d",&val); 
  if(i=0; i>20; i++) { 
    printf("Please enter numbers:"); 
    scanf("%d",&val);
  }
}
```

The expected output for this program should be that it prints out the total number of even and odd numbers. THis is done once the user has entered x amount of values up until a number greater than 20 is entered.

My new code is as follows, however I am very confused on how to define the section for the odd or even numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

int even=0;
int odd=0;
int x;
int num;

while(x<20){
    printf("Please enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    if(x>20){
    for (x = 1; x <= num; x++)
    {
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        even = even + x;
    else
        odd = odd + x;
    }

}}}
```

Comment: "_If someone could assist me with code_" -- That would be _cheating_, not _assisting_. You should do your own homework.

Comment: Show us your attempts.

Comment: You should atleast start by yourself

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hint: read inputs using [scanf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) in a loop and do a conditional check using [if()](http://linux.die.net/man/1/if) for odd number which is greater than `20`. And print the element when above condition passes using [printf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Comment: How about switching to a degree you actually *want* to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question that includes no information on what the author has tried or what is giving them difficulty.

Comment: Suggestion: First write a C program which reads integers from the keyboard, stopping when a number greater than 20 is entered. Then add printing how many numbers there were. Then add conditions. Then add the even/odd distinction.

Comment: So far what I have done is as follows since I am unsure on how to make it stop when a number greater than 20 is inputted.


#include <stdio.h>
 int main(){
 
 int number;
 int i;
 int n;
 int val;
 
 printf("Please enter numbers:");
 scanf("%d",&val);
 
 if(i=0;i>20;i++){
 printf("Please enter numbers:");
 scanf("%d",&val); 
}}

Comment: @CoolGuy This is not home work it is practice which is unmarked.

Comment: @KerrekSB This IS the degree I want to be doing, just because I am struggling does not mean that it is not something that I do not want to be doing. 

If everyone has such a problem with me asking this question then I will go elsewhere.

Comment: @SamLiyanage Not sure what "_it is practice which is unmarked_" means. Nobody is being rude here. Its just that several sites get questions asking to do their homework. Your question looks one of them. If you can edit the question with your attempts, your post would be much better. BTW, this is very basic. Hints for accomplishing it are said by some users in some of the above comments.

Comment: @CoolGuy I am sorry that it has come off as a homework question, I can upload the document somehow if you don't believe me. And yes I am trying to use their hints however loops are not my strong point yet as this is still my first semester

Comment: @SamLiyanage This problem is not with you.  The problem was with the original post.  Adding what you have done so far is a good first step.  You may want to add example input data and expected results.

Comment: @chux I have edited the original post. Sorry I was just unsure about the necessary details a post requires as I am very rushed finding out how to make this work since i don't want to be spending too much time in the exam on a question such as this one

Comment: @SamLiyanage Your code looks awkward. The loop will never execute. Why do you have *two* `scanf`s? Haven't you learnt about `if` statements? Basically, Use a `scanf` with `%d` inside a `while` loop which terminates when the input is greater than 20. If the number is odd, increment an odd counter (by declaring something like `int num_of_odds = 0;` at the beginning) and if it is even, increment the even counter(by declaring something like `int num_of_evens = 0;` at the beginning). Print the results after the loop.

Comment: @CoolGuy Oh I see what you mean, I will start from scratch with a while loop and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: @CoolGuy I have edited it, please see OP for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program should be

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Readability is important. So, indent your code */
/* Notice how I corrected your code and also made it more readable */

int main(void){

    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    int x = 0; /* Initialize x */
    /* int num; Unused variable */

    while(x <= 20 || x % 2 == 0) /* Stop when x is greater than 20 or x is odd */
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a number");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        if (x % 2 == 0)
            even = even + 1; /* +1, not +x. Or `even++;` */
        else
            odd = odd + 1;   /* +1, not +x. Or `odd++;`  */
    }

    printf("Even numbers = %d", even);
    printf("Odd numbers = %d", odd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just have some questions on your code.
"if(x <= 20){ /* Use <=, not > */" Why is it that I should have used one rather than the other.

"int x = 0; /* Initialize x */" Was the reason you put = 0 to have a base point for x to start with? It's little simple things like these which confuse me. Sorry if they are too basic however i just don't want to have little things throwing me off. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: I removed the `if` as I mis-read the question, sorry. `x` is initialized because, if it was not initialized it will have an indeterminate value. So when the execution reaches `while(x < 20 && x % 2 == 1)`, will it be true or false? It could be either true or false or your program might crash etc because you are testing the condition with an uninitialized variable invoking Undefined Behavior. BTW, I edited the program once again.

Comment: And if you still don't get it, feel free to ask me. It doesn't matter if it is a basic question. Glad I could help, BTW

Comment: Oh I see, so almost as a 'failsafe' so to say. now that the code as been set out I can see why everyone said that this was simple. And also when you use "&&"  in the the while statement could it have also been "| |' as it is still showing two conditions? Also do you know of any good coding books that run over things such as that ("even++ things like the plus plus on the end)? Most of the online sources I have found tend to be very confusing on their approach. Currently I am using tutorialspoint.com however a paper book would be much better.

Comment: @SamLiyanage I really got confused. Sorry! Edited the code once again. As for the ++, you should read up on the pre and post increment/decrement operators. In short, If `x = 10` and `y = 20`, then `x = y++;` will make `x = 20` and `y = 21`. On the other hand, `x = ++y` will make `x = 21` and `y = 21`. When used alone, like `y++;` and `++y;`, they do the same thing as `y += 1;` which is the short for `y = y + 1;`

Comment: Oh so was the && wrong or just a syntax error? Ahh kinda makes sense but I will definitely give it a lookup.

Comment: It was wrong, Try thinking if the loop would execute if I used `&&` and `x` is any odd number. `||` is the right thing to use. I agree. It is confusing. `&&` requires both the conditions to be true in order for the whole thing to be true while `||` requires just one of them to be true. And FYI, `&&` is the logical AND operator and `||` is the logical OR operator.

Comment: Oh okay thats not too confusing I guess its mainly just knowing what the conditions are doing, again thank you for your help. Do  I need to somehow close this topic or just leave it?

Comment: @SamLiyanage Just accept an answer (which you've just done) and move on :-)

Comment: i think the condition should be while(x <= 20 && x % 2 == 0)

Comment: @RahulMishra I don't think that's right. Think again. Try the program.

Comment: it is running for x > 20  also like 22,24,26

Comment: @RahulMishra From the question, "...stopping when an **odd** number greater than 20 is entered."

Comment: @CoolGuy ok that fine...I misunderstood...you were right